# Enabled/disabled listener using FusedLocationApi?

Tags: java, android, locationlistener, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

The regular Android (non-Fused) LocationListener

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

has the methods `onProviderEnabled` and `onProviderDisabled`,
so that you can listen for when the user turns off/on the GPS. In the Fused version

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener

there is only `onLocationChanged`.

I'm wondering how to determine when my user turns GPS/location on/off while using the Fused Location API.

Note that this is different from wanting to query once and receive a boolean whether location is enabled or disabled; I need a listener that has a callback to take action upon a change.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LocationAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationAvailability) is probably what you are looking for.

When you call [`requestLocationUpdates`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper)), one of the parameters is a [`LocationCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback) which gives you access to the listener [`onLocationAvailability`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback.html#onLocationAvailability(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationAvailability)).